# Refresh firebase token Flutter and RESTfull API

Tags: flutter, dart, hybrid-mobile-app, mobile-application

How can I refresh firebase token which I get from current user and after put it in API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you receive firebase token, you also get in response  **refresh_token** property. You can save it, and later send POST request to:

```
https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token?key=[API_KEY]
```

with body:

grant_type: refresh_token

refresh_token: [**refresh_token**]

More details here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-refresh-token

```
// Sign In with email and password
  var signInResponse = await http.post(
    Uri.parse(
        'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=[API_KEY]'),
    body: {
      "email": "example@example.com",
      "password": "example",
      "returnSecureToken": "true"
    },
  );

  var jsonSignInResponse =
      jsonDecode(signInResponse.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
  
  // This refresh token you can use to refresh your auth token
  var refreshToken = jsonSignInResponse['refreshToken'];

  // Make suchlike request when you need to refresh your auth token
  var refreshResponse = await http.post(
    Uri.parse(
        'https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token?key=[API_KEY]'),
    body: {
      "grant_type": "refresh_token",
      "refresh_token": refreshToken,
    },
  );

  // Here you get your refreshed auth token -> jsonRefreshResponse['id_token']
  var jsonRefreshResponse =
      jsonDecode(refreshResponse.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Can u write any example snippet please?